# GHC & Cabal on Raspberry Pi 4 with Debian Buster

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

Is there already a way to install GHC & Cabal on a Raspberry Pi with Debian Buster?
https://downloads.haskell.org/~debian/

I need to port an already existing code to the new Raspberry Pi 4.

Thanks and best regards,
Manuel

Comment: take a look [here](https://svejcar.dev/posts/2019/09/23/haskell-on-raspberry-pi-4/) if `stack`-based approach would be an option.

Comment: Thanks @palik. I have no experience with this stuff. I just have to port an existing game which was started by "runhaskell srcipt.hs". I can't figure out how to do this after configuration of the stack like described in your link. Thanks

Comment: As of November 2023, `cabal` and `ghc` are easily installed on Raspberry pi 4 (64 bit) with `sudo apt-get install cabal-install`